# Mapping a react component doesn't return to the parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a two components. One component `Profileviewlist` is a child of `Profileview` mapping components inside of `Profileviewlist` returns a child component outside of `Profileview` . I have been looking around on this site for this issue. I am looking for a way to get `Profileviewlist`'s components to render inside of `Profileview`. Any insight helps.

Note: The components render , just not in the parent(profileview).

**Profile view:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Profileviewheader from './profileviewheader'
import Profileviewlist from './Profileviewlist'

export default function Profileview({ persons, display_selector }) {
  if (persons == null || persons.status == "error") {
    return (
      <Profileviewheader />
    )
  }
  else {
    console.log("rendering list")
    console.log()
    return (
      <>
        <Profileviewheader />
        <Profileviewlist persons={persons} display_selector={display_selector} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

** Profile view list:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Profileviewchild from './profileviewchild';

export default function Profileviewlist({ persons, display_selector }) {
  return (
    persons.map(person => {
      return <Profileviewchild person={person} change_selected={display_selector} />
    })
  )
}
```

**Parental Hierarchy(the way I would like the components to be structured in the form of divs) Each component points to its child:**

Profileview:->
Profileviewlist:->
Profileviewchild:

Comment: so many `Profileview`, can you explain better with `children` and `parent` words?

Comment: The profileview is the overall parent. The profile view list is a child of profileview. profileview child is a child of profileviewlist.  Something like this : {Profileview:{Profileviewlist:{Profileviewchild}}}

Comment: Does your `ProfileViewList` renders? do you get `console.log("rendering list")` in the `console`?

Comment: @TaghiKhavari yes everything renders. The only issue is the rendered elements are not inside of profileview. https://imgur.com/a/T45kkG2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you have a list of personal profiles, you should make a ternary operator for checking if `persons` not null and have a length then map into them, else show an error.

Something like this should work:

```
export default function Profileview({ persons, display_selector }) {
  return (
    <div id="profileview">
      <Profileviewheader />
      {persons.length ? persons.map(person => (
        <Profileviewchild person={person} change_selected={display_selector} />
      )) :
        <p>{persons.status}</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Edit**:
After checking the shared picture, the problem is you assign `id="profileview"` on the `Profileviewheader`. you should assign this component.

Comment: Profileviewchild still appears outside of profile view. when taking a look at the dom.Other than that, great way for cutting out the middle man which was profileviewlist.

Comment: yes, it's just unnecessary. can you share a picture of what you mean?

Comment: can you share `Profileviewheader` i think you name the `id="profileview"` on the `Profileviewheader`? try answer again show me result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring by `persons` in `Profileview` and `Profileviewlist`

Here the type of `persons` seems to be `Object`.

So `persons.map()` will never work since `map` is the method of `Array` not `Object`. The ideal way is that `persons` have `list` key field.

```json
{
   status: 'success',
   list: [...] // persons list
}
```

```js
   ...
   <Profileviewlist persons={persons.list} display_selector={display_selector} />
   ...
```

Comment: Persons is an array of objects but it could also be just an object. That is why I check to see if it has the .status field. Persons could be either {user:{moredata:"123"}} or {status:"error"}

Comment: persons can be array and object at the same time when the error comes he can pass `person.status = "error"`